# Weighted random number (without predefined values!)

Tags: random, game-maker

currently I'm needing a function which gives a weighted, random number.
It should chose a random number between two doubles/integers (for example 4 and 8) while the value in the middle (6) will occur on average, about twice as often than the limiter values 4 and 8.
If this were only about integers, I could predefine the values with variables and custom probabilities, but I need the function to give a double with at least 2 digits (meaning thousands of different numbers)!

The environment I use, is the "Game Maker" which provides all sorts of basic random-generators, but not weighted ones.

Could anyone possibly lead my in the right direction how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of two independent continuous uniform(0,1)'s, `U1` and `U2`, has a continuous symmetrical triangle distribution between 0 and 2.  The distribution has its peak at 1 and tapers to zero at either end.  We can easily translate that to a range of (4,8) via scaling by 2 and adding 4, i.e., `4 + 2*(U1 + U2)`.

However, you don't want a height of zero at the endpoints, you want half the peak's height. In other words, you want a triangle sitting on a rectangular base (i.e., uniform), with height `h` at the endpoints and height `2h` in the middle.  That makes life easy, because the triangle must have a peak of height `h` above the rectangular base, and a triangle with height `h` has half the area of a rectangle with the same base and height `h`.  It follows that 2/3 of your probability is in the base, 1/3 is in the triangle.

Combining the elements above leads to the following pseudocode algorithm.  If `rnd()` is a function call that returns continuous uniform(0,1) random numbers:

```
define makeValue()
   if rnd() <= 2/3    # Caution, may want to use 2.0/3.0 for many languages
      return 4 + (4 * rnd())
   else
      return 4 + (2 * (rnd() + rnd()))
```

I cranked out a million values using that and plotted a histogram:

[image: House-shaped distribution]

Comment: Thank you VERY much! Interesting concept and works well!

Comment: @DragonGamer I can't claim credit for any of the pieces.  Summing random variables is called convolution, assembling a distribution from component pieces is called composition.  Both are well known techniques in the simulation community.

Answer (score 2):

For the case someone needs this in Game Maker (or a different language ) as an universal function:

```
if random(1) <= argument0
   return argument1 + ((argument2-argument1) * random(1))
else
   return argument1 + (((argument2-argument1)/2) * (random(1) + random(1)))
```

Called as follows (similar to the standard random_range function):

`val = weight_random_range(FACTOR, FROM, TO)`

"FACTOR" determines how much of the whole probability figure is the "base" for constant probability. E.g. 2/3 for the figure above.
0 will provide a perfect triangle and 1 a rectangle (no weightning).