# Javascript Random url redirect with different odds

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that on page load redirects to different url's based on a random number (from the number of links provided). It works fine.

What i'm trying to do is to control the odds of each link being loaded.

To be more precise, I want only the first link to have the lowest chance of "winning".

```js
var links = [
  "flip1.html",
  "flip2.html",
  "flip3.html",
  "flip4.html",
  "flip5.html"
]
var openSite = function() {
  // get a random number between 0 and the number of links
  var randIdx = Math.random() * links.length;
  // round it, so it can be used as array index
  randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);
  // construct the link to be opened
  var link = 'http://' + links[randIdx];

  var win = window.open(link, '_self');
  win.focus();

};
```

```html
<body onload="javascript:openSite();" style="height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding:0px; ">
```

Comment: should it be an array of string? or we can make an array of object like `[{"url":"page1.html", "odds": 10},{"url":"page2.html", "odds": 4}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a weight to every possible option.

Then, you can generate a random on the sum of weights and see where the random hits:

```js
var links = [
  { url: "flip1.html", weight: 1 }, // 5%
  { url: "flip2.html", weight: 2 }, // 10%
  { url: "flip3.html", weight: 3 }, // 15%
  { url: "flip4.html", weight: 4 }, // 20%
  { url: "flip5.html", weight: 10 } // 50%
];

function weightedRandom(arr)
{
  var weightSum = arr.map(l => l.weight).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  var rand = Math.random() * weightSum;
  
  var accumulated = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if (rand < accumulated + arr[i].weight)
    {
      return arr[i];
    }
    
    accumulated += arr[i].weight;
  }
}

function openSite() {
  var link = weightedRandom(links);
  
  // uncomment this and call openSite function:
  //var win = window.open(link.url, '_self');
  //win.focus();
}

function experiment()
{
  var testsCount = 10000;
  var counts = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  {
    counts[links[i].url] = 0;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < testsCount; i++)
  {
    var link = weightedRandom(links);
    counts[link.url]++;
  }
  
  console.log(counts);
}

experiment();
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great! thanks. How do i control the weight? since i need just flip1 to be 4% and the rest to be the same odds (24%)

Comment: I don't know if I like this game fixing you are doing xD.  You could also directly reduce in one step `arr.reduce((acc, l) => acc + l.weight, 0);`

Comment: Thanks @Avin. it's not game fixing, it's a prize with bigger value therefore has lower chance of winning. only logical. didn't understand where to place this line?

Comment: `var weightSum = arr.reduce((acc, l) => acc + l.weight, 0);`. Saves a few microseconds, nothing much. The beauty of this code is you can use exactly the numbers you want them to be without doing any fractional calculations. so replace the weights by `4, 24, 24, 24, 24` in that order.

Answer (score 0):

you can add same links multiple times to array

for example: 
link1 with 10% chance, link2 with 50% chance, link3 with 40% chance

needed array for this chances:

```
var links = [
   'link1', // single link1
   'link2', // five times link2
   'link2',
   'link2',
   'link2',
   'link2',
   'link3', // four times link3
   'link3',
   'link3',
   'link3',
]
```

then you can shuffle the array and get values from it randomly

the chance for link1 will be about 10%

Comment: found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915888/weighted-random-number-without-predefined-values